# iOS GoogleMap SDK usage limit

Tags: google-maps-sdk-ios

I develop an app that uses GoogleMapSDK. Currently I use **GMSMapView** to display map, and **GMSGeocoder** to get region name. And I need to know if there is usage limitation for this

I found a statement [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#usage_apis) stating 'native Maps APIs for mobile platforms such as Android and iOS are not affected'. But I'm not sure if both classes I use counted as native Map APIs.

So my question : Is there any usage limit/quota for GMSMapView/GMSGeocoder or maybe any other class in SDK?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The native Google Maps API for iOS means the entire iOS SDK documented at  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/reference/index. This includes GMSMapView and GMSGeocoder, and so there are no usage limits for those classes, or for any other classes in that SDK.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Now I'm sure about this